# CoroutineLiveData emits null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

I'm learning *Android LiveData*. I have the code

```
    private lateinit var questionCounterTotal: LiveData<Int>
```

inside *Fragment*'s `onCreateView`:

```
questionList = questionViewModel.getAllQuestions()
questionCounterTotal = liveData { emit(44) }

//this line prints null 
questionCounterTotal.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,Observer<Int>{value->
    Log.d("amin",value.toString())
})

//this line prints null too
Log.d("amin",questionCounterTotal.value.toString())
```

As comments describe, I can't print the `questionCouterTotal` value when the code is hosted in *Fragment*, but the code works fine if it is inside of an *Activity*. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because a *LiveData* value won't be emitted until its observer is in an active state. From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#:%7E:text=LiveData%20considers%20an%20observer%2C%20which,the%20STARTED%20or%20RESUMED%20state.):

> LiveData considers an observer, which is represented by the Observer class, to be in an active state if its lifecycle is in the STARTED or RESUMED state.

Let me add extra logs to demonstrate the above said.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val questionCounterTotal = liveData {
        Log.d("amin", "Emitting 44")
        emit(44)
    }
    Log.d("amin", "The line after liveData { }")

    questionCounterTotal.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer<Int>{ value->
        Log.d("amin","Observing value: $value")
    })

    Log.d("amin", "onViewCreated: ${questionCounterTotal.value.toString()}")
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    Log.d("amin", "onStart")
}
```

That gives the following output:

```
D/amin: The line after liveData { }
D/amin: onViewCreated: null
D/amin: onStart
D/amin: Emitting 44
D/amin: Observing value: 44
```

Comment: thanks.what about when there is no observer?will it run `Log.d("amin", "Emitting 44")` inside livedata builder?